# Graphing/Crystal Reports with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, crystal-reports, graph

I would like to add graphing to my User Controls in ASP.NET MVC. I am hoping for some ideas or a guide on how to approach this issue. I have searched around and found no helpful answers to resolve this issue. I was thinking of doing crystal reports but they don't boat over well in ASP.NET from my previous experience. I would just like to know some ways to go about tackling this problem. So again what I'm trying to do is add graphing to MVC User Controls from a ViewDataDictionary that's passed to my User Control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go with [google charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) for free, or something like [Dundas](http://www.dundas.com) (which is EXCELLENT) if you are willing to pay.

I hope I've understood your question.

Answer (score 2):

I have been happy using the [JFreeChart.net](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=151482&package_id=207833) graphing system. It is a port / semi-port of javas famous JFreechart. It has alot of capabilities, and the output looks very good.

It took me 30 minutes to do my first graph, but that was mostly because you have to pay for the documentation (not the code), so i was working off the samples, which I later found to be very adequate.

[Screenshots and examples are shown here](http://www.ujihara.jp/jbyjsharp/jfreechart/results/)

[alt text http://www.ujihara.jp/jbyjsharp/jfreechart/results/PieChartDemo1.png](http://www.ujihara.jp/jbyjsharp/jfreechart/results/PieChartDemo1.png)

[alt text http://www.ujihara.jp/jbyjsharp/jfreechart/results/RingChartDemo1.png](http://www.ujihara.jp/jbyjsharp/jfreechart/results/RingChartDemo1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Flex Charting, ChartDirector and Yahoo's Charts are decent. Chart Director has a good support net, and the guy is very responsive to questions and feature requests.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out [.dot net charting](http://www.dotnetcharting.com/).  We've been using it for a few years at my job and it's worked fairly good for us.  We build reports internally through various systems and it has served us well so far.